# How do I create a custom website-based puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-creation

There's a few examples out there of websites which show you a clue / hint, and if you guess the correct password you get to the next level.

Some e.g.:

- http://www.totallytricky.co.uk/riddle/ame.php
- http://journal29.com/12/

Is there a quick way to create such custom websites?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question about *puzzles* - it seems more of a question about website-building. (I wouldn't ask how to make, say, a cooking blog on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: I partly agree and partly disagree wtih @Deusovi. I think it is valid to ask on this forum if there are some "quick and easy" tools others have used for exactly this purpose, but the question is bordering off-topic for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have full controll over your webpage and it is a simple "HTML only" webspace for you, the easiest way is to have each puzzle end with a "keyword" or "key-number" which is not too short, and to have the user enter that "key" to the webdomain.

> Example:
>
> You create a puzzle that results in the key `YHU124MEMAMO`. This
>   puzzle page is hosted on the webserver under a link like
>
> `www.mydomain.puzzle.org/startpage.htm`
>
> and the "next" page you want people to visit after solving is stored
>   with the name
>
> `www.mydomain.puzzle.org/YHU124MEMAMO.htm`

This is of course not very elegant, but it is quick and easy to do and does not require any specific HTML knowledge.

This type of "hide-away the next step" has also been frequently used by puzzles on this site here. I used this technique myself in some of my puzzles like in "[A pirate's treasure-hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33554/a-pirates-treasure-hunt)". Here, the build-up is slighlty different, because you don't controll the URL directly. I've uploaded images first - which auto-generates a link with some arbitrary "key" - and then I've build the puzzle so that this link becomes the solution.

Alternatively, you might also consider using any of the [URL abbreviation services](https://www.lifewire.com/shortening-long-links-3486603) out there like [Bitly](https://bitly.com/). The idea here being that the "result" of your puzzle gives you a shortened URL which you can link to any webpage location you like. Thus, you don't need control over the exact URL you puzzle pages are on, which can be helpful when you're using any semi-automated web-creation tool or content-managment-system.

This is just a short answer. But as pointed out by Deusovi, going any deeper is rather a quation on "how to implement stuff on the web" than puzzle-related and should possibly be asked elsewhere.

Comment: [Notpron](http://www.notpron.com/) is a great example of a puzzle site where a lot of the solutions involve simply changing the page URLs.